# Are there any congruence relations on $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ besides mod n?

Tags: universal-algebra

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$. Are there any congruence relations on that structure, in the sense of universal algebra, that are not of the form mod n for some integer n? In fact, is there a classification of all the congruence relations on that structure?

Comment: How about $a\sim b$ when $a$ and $b$ "have the same sign"?

Comment: @RobArthan I think you misunderstand. I think Angina is referring to the relation, "a and b are both zero or both positive or both negative"

Comment: Another example is the relation "$a \sim b$ iff $\frac{a}{b}$ is a nonzero rational square or $a=b=0$". Yet another example is the relation of having the same absolute value.

Comment: Mea culpa for a dumb comment and a dumb answer. The OP needs to tidy up the question:  "mod n for some n" isn't very clear.

Comment: What is the operation? $*$ would normally be understood to be multiplication, in which case, are you looking at monoid congruences?

Comment: It's a bit easier to think about $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}_{>0};\times)$ first - that already has lots of additional congruences, and it's much snappier to describe structurally (it's the free monoid on $\aleph_0$-many generators). Every congruence of $\mathcal{N}$ lifts to a congruence of $\mathcal{Z}=(\mathbb{Z};\times)$ via the $\mathcal{Z}$-congruence $\{(x,y):\vert x\vert=\vert y\vert\}$.